# tools for downloading files from websites in linux

Tags: linux, internet

How do you download files, such as mp3/pdf/doc, from websites in linux OS, such as Ubuntu?

I know wget is a good tool, anything else?

PS:

Many downloading tools, such as eMule, are better than wget in terms of downloading speed, right?

Comment: `wget` and `curl` are pretty good, but I'd say `wget` is the standard. Also, this might be a little off-topic here.

Comment: In response to your edit, eMule is P2P, isn't it? Not exactly a replacement?

Comment: @DanFego, yes, :), so how do you usually download staff in linux? Any other tools?

Comment: if I were downloading a bunch of files from a website, I'd use `wget` or a web browser. `wget` has spidering functionality that might be helpful for downloading a lot of files.

Comment: Lynx a command line browser, give it a try

Answer (score 5):

`wget` is strong enough for almost any use. You just have to know know how to use it.

You can write your own script which acts like DAP in shell environment. For example running several instances of `wget` in background will increase your download rate and speed...

```
wget http://wxyz.abc/def.pdf &
```

(notice the ampersand) and so on.

If you are not restricted to text mode, you may use FlashGet and lots of other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

[`axel`](http://axel.alioth.debian.org/) (the site is down as of this posting - it may come back later) is a nice little tool for downloading files which downloads over multiple connections. Anything large, like distribution ISO's, I try to download using `axel`.

However, depending on use, `wget` may be better - it has many more commandline switches and countermeasures to sites that don't like downloaders, as well as a lot of other stuff (`man wget | nl` reports 1288 lines - `axel's` man page is only 97 lines long).